# Why does this TypedQuery result in a very slow execution?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

My code looks like:

```
public Reservation findParametersToReport (Long external_id, Long client_id) {
String q = "Select r from Reservation r where r.client_id =:" + CLIENT_ID + "and external_id =:" + EXTERNAL_ID;

TypedQuery <Reservation> query = entityManager.createQuery (q, Reservation.class)
.setParameter (CLIENT_ID, client_id)
.setParameter (EXTERNAL_ID, external_id);

Reservation r = query.getSingleResult ();
return r;
}
```

It is very slow: about 4 minutes! The same database query is done in 200ms

She stands the longest on:

```
Reservation r = query.getSingleResult ();
```

The Reservation entity has only one reference of the OneToMany type (and it is lazy), while it has many BigDecimal fields.
The table itself in the database is also large: it has 6 million records

I have no idea what could be the reason - I tried to select only the fields of interest to me (query below), which are the most important to me - and the execution time was shortened by ... 7 seconds.

```
      public ReservationParamsDTO findParametersToReport (Long external_id, Long client_id) { 
//r.id - type Long, r.netAmount - type BigDecimal, r.date_of_arrival - type Date
    String q = "Select new com.example.dto.ReservationParamsDTO (r.id, r.netAmount, r.date_of_arrival) from Reservation r where r.client_id =:" + CLIENT_ID + "and external_id =:" + EXTERNAL_ID;
        
        TypedQuery <ReservationParamsDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery (q, ReservationParamsDTO .class) 
    .setParameter (CLIENT_ID, client_id) 
    .setParameter (EXTERNAL_ID, external_id);
        
        ReservationParamsDTO r = query.getSingleResult (); 
    return r; }
```

Can you please provide me with an hint regarding where shall I start looking to improve performance in this scenario? Please let me know, if you require more information.

Comment: I assume that you have lazy relationships in Reservation that are loaded. Please turn SQL logging on an check the generated SQL

Comment: @SzymonMartinelli The generated SQL is normal and I really don't know what's going on, why it's been so long:
select
reservation0_.id as id1_200_0_,
reservation0_.net_amount as net_amount2_200_0_,
reservation0_date_of_arrival as date_of_arri21_200_0
from
public.reservation reservation0_
where
reservation0_.external_id =?
and reservation0_.client_id =?

Comment: @jjanes : I copied the above generated query and ran it directly on the database via pgAdmin

Comment: I don't know why it would be so slow in the database.  Maybe the slowness is on the client side (although I don't know why that would be, either).  You could clarify by setting up auto_explain to capture plans of slow queries, with auto_explain.log_analyze turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out where the issue is located: on the database side or in your app.
First of all, enable logging of generated sql queries.
Then take one of queries and execute on your database with explaining:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select ... -- your query here
```

You should get a query plan like this:

```
Seq Scan on dict_product_catalog  (cost=0.00..9.28 rows=13 width=40) (actual time=0.043..0.046 rows=3 loops=1)
  Filter: (product_code = '5081'::bigint)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 3
  Buffers: shared hit=9
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=73
Planning Time: 0.367 ms
Execution Time: 0.092 ms
```

Or you can set up auto_explain extension as suggested earlier in comments.
If query cost and execution time is OK the issue is probably on the app side.